# Display 2 divs on top of each other, while one is dependant on others divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow

I need to have 3 divs on page:

`left (fixed size) | middle (all available space) | right (fixed size)`

The problem is that I do not have enought space to display all information in `left div`, because in that case my `middle div` will become too small, so user experience wil be affected in a negative way :) Wrapping is also not an option because information in `left div` becomes messy.

So I came up with the solution to display one more div on top on `left div`. Let's call it `left div 2` with style `overflow: hidden;`. Using the `jQuery` I will expand the size of `left div 2` when user hovers over it.
**In theory - the size of the `middle div` will remain the same.** And when the focus is lost on `left div 2` - it's size will go back to normal!

I am currently stuck at `CSS` layout which is getting out of control... Here is the closest result that I have came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/KLXPL/11/

Now, I would like to request Your assistance on this task! Of course, I am also open to suggestions if there are better ways to accomplish this task..

Here is an image of what I want to achieve. Please excuse my painting skills.
[image]

P.S. while I was writing this text I think I have came up with one more solution. `right div` will be alligned to right with fixed size (just like now). `Middle div` should have a left margin? set to `200px` and width to 100% and aligment to right. `left div 2` is not necessary because `middle div` is using the left spacing from left border of the **screen** (not another div)... so.. Haven't tried any of that yet. But even if I tried - my css is the worst :)

Comment: Does absolute positioning not solve it? Giving `left div 2` absolute positioning and use a CSS-transition on hover is what comes to mind.

Comment: You really don't need JavaScipt to expand the size of the `left div 2`. Have you thought about tablet users? They don't have a 'hover'.

Comment: @Roy, maybe I will just add an "Expand" button on top of the div for tablet users :) But this is a good point indeed!

Comment: @Alex Is my answer below ok? Or do you want to use JQuery?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith, I left a comment under your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need JQuery to achieve this.

Here is your original fiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/KLXPL/12/

Here is an example with using only CSS https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/12/

HTML example:

```
<div class="div1">
  <h1>Some text that should not break</h1>
  <p>Some text that should not break to new line</p>
</div>
<div class="div2">

</div>
<div class="div3">

</div>
```

CSS example:

```
.div1,
.div2,
.div3 {
  float: left;
}

.div1,
.div3 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 600px;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute; // to place on top
  z-index: 2;// to place on top
  white-space: nowrap;// to keep from wrapping
  overflow: hidden //to not show overflow
}

.div1:hover {
  width: 550px;
}

.div2 {
  width: calc(100% - 300px);//sets 100% of remaining width
  height: 600px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 150px;//Since div1 has absolute position and z-index of 2, 
                     //this sets the div to apear next to div 1
}

.div3 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks Adam! Your solution is exactly what i wanted! Although I think I will switch to `jQuery` solution for 2 reasons. 1 - it gives me an option to animate slide effect. 2 - I can make a separate button (aimed at tablet users) to manually hide/show side div.

Comment: @Alex You could still animate it and add a button without the use of jquery.

Comment: awesome! thank you! What is your person opinion about animation - should I go with `CSS` or `jQuery`? Can you confirm if `jQuery` solution will be supported by more browsers than `CSS` animation?

Comment: @Alex Yes, jquery would be better. also it would be smoother.

Answer (score 1):

So, @Adam Buchanan Smith, solved the problem of css layout. But as I noticed you wanted to have two divs on left, one above other, but only one of them being dependent on other divs for size.

So picking up from what @Adam gave, here is the correct solution. div left is fixed size, it doesn't enlarge on hover, but only the left2(which contains the long text) resizes on hover. Both divs are however above each other, just as wanted.

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/daveRexter/syah6soc/7/

```
<header>
<div class="left-side"> <!-- div for whole left section -->
<div class="left">LEFT div</div>
<div class="left2">
<p>
  my very long text which should be hidden with overflow
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="center">CENTER div</div>
<div class="right">RIGHT div</div>
</header>
```

CSS Code:

```
body {
margin: 0px;
}

header {
color: white;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
background-color: #2995f3;
}

.center {
 width: calc(100% - 400px);
 background: green;
 margin-left: 200px;
 float: left;
 }
 .left {
 float: left;
 background: red;
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 }
.left2 {
float: left;
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
overflow: hidden; // to hide the overflow of long text
}
p{background-color: red; white-space: nowrap;}
.left2:hover{width: calc(100% - 200px);}
.right {
float: left;
background: red;
width: 200px;
}
```

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Adam's solution is correct. I think there was a misunderstanding.. What I meant is "above `Z` axis" and you interpret is as "above `Y` axis". I made an image to made it more clear in my initial post. But thanks for yet another solution.